# Recursion out of heap memory, but not with (longer) loop?

Tags: java, recursion, out-of-memory

I have a hierarchical lattice structure where each node has some parents and children. For an object to be added to a node it must satisfy the rules of that node. The nodes are such that the the objects contained within the children are subsets of the objects in the parent(s). When I add an object at the moment I am running through the entire lattice to add the object.

```
    foreach Object g
          foreach Node in Lattice

             add g to Node

          End for
    End for
```

Although this is simple, the lattice is very large and there are a lot of objects to get through, so this seems like a waste of time (although there is no heap space with this method) because there are many nodes that the particular object may not be valid for.

I rather need to improve the performance of the program in this area and have therefore implemented a recursive function that will only add the objects to the top of the lattice and then carry on to try and add it to the children if it is successful:

```
   foreach Object g
         topNode.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(g)
   End for
```

Where the recursive method is

```
   addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(Object obj){
          boolean success = addObject(obj)
          if(success)
               foreach kid in Children
                    kid.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(obj);
               End for
   }
```

When using the recursion technique after about 16000 objects I get a heap error, but can't think why? it is clearly working for the first 15000 or so, any help would be much appreciated. I hope I have given enough information and that I have done something ridiculously stupid.

```
Movie movie;    

try {
movie = data.getAFilm(index);

    //This piece of code works
    //for(RatingConcept r : concepts)
          //r.addOneObject(movie);

    //but this piece of code doesn't!
    concepts.get(0).addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(movie);


index++;
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }

    //The next three methods are within the concept class
public void addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(Movie movie) {
            boolean success = addOneObject(movie);

    if(success){
        for(Concept kid : this.children){
             kid.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(movie);
        }
    }

}

public boolean addOneObject(Movie addMe) {
    if (valid(addMe,minIndex,maxIndex,minValue,maxValue)) {
        objects.add(addMe); 
        hasSomething = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected static boolean valid(Movie test, int minIndex, int maxIndex,
                                    int minValue, int maxValue) {
    int[] distribution = test.getDistribution();

// to be valid only look at the range given by indexMax and Min Index
// and then see if they lie within the value ranges

     for(int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i ++){
     if(distribution[i] > maxValue || distribution[i] < minValue){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just so we are clear, this is the error

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-3" Rating thread finished
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at e.RatingConcept.addOneObject(RatingConcept.java:83)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:142)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingConcept.addObjectToMeAndAllChildren(RatingConcept.java:144)
at e.RatingBuilder.run(RatingBuilder.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Code is needed here; apart from that, have you tried and increased your heap size?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a heap error? If your recursive method can't be made tail-recursive, then I would think that the recursive function calls might have used up all the available stack.

Comment: There _is_ tail recursion optimization in some JVMs but not all; this cannot be accounted for in the general case

Comment: I don't say that this must be the reason, but something I'd check. Not every recursive function can be optimized that way, after all.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-3" Rating thread finished
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
 at e.RatingConcept.addOneObject(RatingConcept.java:83)